# Console based menu in bash

Tags: bash, menu, console

can anyone tell me how can i build console based menu in which i can navigate by direction keys to select options. Code should be in bash or shell script.

Comment: That's fantastic. So, [what have you tried yourself?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: @J.Steen, i have tried tput cup to do this thing and array to store options but that is not what i am thinking about. can you suggest me any other approach ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at [pdmenu](http://joeyh.name/code/pdmenu/). It is pretty simple to use.

Or in case you need go deeper there is [whiptail](http://linux.die.net/man/1/whiptail) tool. It also allow you to build dialog box and so on. But it is a little bit harder to use comparing to `pdmenu`.

Comment: thank you, i will to do this thing with your suggested tool.

Answer (score 1):

What about the [dialog](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dialog) command?

Comment: Sorry, Sir i am new for Linux. so i don't know about 'dialog' command if you give some reference then it would be better for me.

Comment: @AnandSwaroop: I gave a reference. Click the word "dialog" in my answer.